# WCF channel randomly becomes Faulted (upon thread termination)

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

Our application is composed of 2 application domains.
Some method calls (logging) in the secondary appdomain **must** be "redirected" to the first appdomain.

This is done by setting up a WCF service on the main appdomain, and having the secondary appdomain call its operations.

For example, here's code that runs in the 2nd AppDomain:

```
Logger.Debug("Message");
```

Will internally be redirected as a WCF service call to the first AppDomain:

```
public void Debug(string message)
{
    if (useService)
    {
        logProxy.Log(message);
    }
}
```

The problem is that on **random** occasions, i'm seeing the service proxy transition into the **Faulted** state.

Digging deeper, I've found out that when the thread that makes the service calls gets shut down, on some occasions the proxy object will become faulted.

My question is -- how can i protect myself from the scenario where a WCF service call is performed, but the thread that started the call gets shutdown? (possibly before receiving a reply).

Also -- is ClientBase favorable over using the ChannelFactory option for creating a client proxy?

Some extra details on my setup:

- WCF Service is exposed via a NetNamedPipeBinding (named pipes)
- I am using the ChannelFactory.CreateChannel method for creating the "client" proxy (not ClientBase).

Answer (score 1):

Only the client can handle this.

```
ServiceClient client = new ServiceClient();
 try {
     client.Operation();
 }
 catch(Exception ex)
 {
     if (client.State == CommunicationState.Faulted)
     {
             client.Abort();
             client = new ServiceClient();
     }
 }
```

Comment: Can there be any logical explanation on why it turns to Faulted? Aren't the service calls (by default) blocking? meaning the call should return after finished, making the thread termination go successfully without invalidating the proxy.

Comment: My bad, crappy answer from me, there could be any number of reasons why, can you provide more specific info regarding the nature of the operating environment? (network equipment being traversed, no. of calls being made, size of data being sent)

Comment: Hard to tell, since the issue is pretty random. The binding used is IPC though, meaning no actual "network" connection is made per se (used as interprocess/appdomain communication).

Comment: Hmm, that rules out app pool restart issues (where the service restarts whilst the client makes a call).  I'm assuming you've tried adding an exception wrapper around the client as this would give you a fuller error (assuming include exceptions was enabled).  The next step would be to enable WCF diagnostics and peeking into the log file it generates to see if the error is logged via the service.

Comment: Include Exceptions is enabled. Diagnostics is a bit harder for random issues, since there may be some time until the issue is reproduced, making it hard to run in diagnostic mode for long periods.

Comment: True, but it's difficult to debug and solve the problem further without knowing how to reproduce it. It might be the only way, else were just going to try random things without knowing if it's resolved or not.